# Keeping track of number of touch events in the past 15 minutes

Tags: java, android, arrays

In my Android application I'm keeping track of touch events. For every touch event I also have a timestamp in milliseconds. Now, I would like to calculate in a fast way how many touch events happended in the past 15 minutes. Of course, I could just store all timestamps in a list or array and iterate over the list but the list will grow fast and this is also inefficient if I have to do this calculation every second.

What is the best way to keep track of how many touch events happened in the past 15 minutes? I have a background thread which needs information about how many touch events happened in the past 15 minutes every second.

Comment: As you may notice, there are sometimes that there's a touch burst. What I mean touch burst is a sequence of close touched points that happened in a short period of time. For example, when the user drags or flings something. You can group them and put the total number in an item with a timestamp in a queue or list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you can't do any better than having a list of the timestamps, but there are some optimisations you can apply.

1. Take advantage of the list being implicitly sorted
2. Use a [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (because you are adding at the end and popping from the start)
3. Avoid iterating the whole list - you can simply check the first element of the list and see if it's 15 minutes old or not

If it's appropriate, I guess you could use Handler.postDelayed for 15 minutes, but you would probably run into issues if you try to keep track of touch events past app or even device reboots, whereas you could use SharedPreferences with a Deque-based solution.

I'm not convinced that Handler.postDelayed would actually be any more efficient than using a Deque, but it offloads the logic away from your app so you don't have to deal with it :P